# Dynamic templates for listview/Radlistview

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview, webforms, radlistview

I am trying to accomplish the task of loading a template into a listview depending on the data coming in and what the text in the field "Type" has in it.

At the state i am at the templates will load and perform as needed but not on the record i am currently am working with, it will produce the template on the next record instead.

```
    protected void RadListView1_OnItemDataBound(object sender, RadListViewItemEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Item.ItemType == RadListViewItemType.DataItem || e.Item.ItemType == RadListViewItemType.AlternatingItem)
        {
            RadListViewDataItem dataItem = (RadListViewDataItem)e.Item;
            DataRowView rowView = (DataRowView)dataItem.DataItem;

            string Keyword = rowView["Type"].ToString();

            if (keyword == "anothertest")
            {
                RadListView1.ItemTemplate = LoadTemplate("Cash.ascx");
            }
            else if (keyword == "test")
            {
                RadListView1.ItemTemplate = LoadTemplate("Credits.ascx");
            }
        }
    }
```

this is how i am currently achieving this, do i need to complete this method on something other than "onItemDataBound" to work on the current record? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Put a breakpoint on the OnItemDataBound event and see if there is a different item type than the two you are checking for that is being used for the current record. `e.Item.ItemType` might not be one of those two you are checking for.

Comment: the item type is only used to collect the fields data which in one case would be "anothertest" matching the first part of the inner if statement thus setting the item template to "cash.ascx" this is what i want but it doesn't set the existing record template that fired that event to the new template. it just uses the old one.